# PodioConnectionError for localhost using PHP client library

Tags: php, apache, curl, openssl, podio

I used OpenSSL to generate an SSL Certificate for my localhost, but the self-signed certificate seems to be causing problems when authenticating with Podio:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PodioConnectionError: Connection to Podio API failed: [60] SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

I tried downloading `cacert.pem` and adding it to my php.ini file `curl.cainfo=<path-to>cacert.pem`, but after restarting the server, I still get the same error.

With some other library's I've had to set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`, but I'm not sure how I would do that anyway using the Podio PHP client library...

Any tips on debugging this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out [how to set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false](https://github.com/podio-community/podio-php/blob/master/lib/Podio.php) when using the Podio PHP client library:

```
$options = array('curl_options' => array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false));
Podio::setup($client_id, $client_secret, $options);
```

Now I just have to remember to remove this in production...